# Pandas group, aggregate two columns and return the earliest Start Date for one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to group by a csv file in Pandas (by one column: ID) in order to get the earliest Start Date and latest End Date. Then I am trying to group by multiple columns in order to get the SUM of a value. For each ID in the second groupedby dataframe, I want to present the dates.

I am loading a csv in order to group and aggregate data.

**01)** First I load the csv

```
def get_csv():
        #Read csv file
        df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1",parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date'])

        return df
```

**02)** Group and aggregate the data for the columns (ID and Site)

```
def do_stuff():
     df = get_csv()   
     groupedBy = df[df['A or B'].str.contains('AAAA')].groupby([df['ID'], df['Site'].fillna('Other'),]).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
```

which works as expected and I am getting the following (example):

[image]

**03)** And ideally, for the same ID I want to present the earliest date in the Start Date column and the latest one in the End Date column. The aggregation for the value works perfectly. What I want to get is the following:

[image]

I do not know how to change my current code above. I have tried this so far:

```
def do_stuff():
    df = get_csv()
    md = get_csv()

    minStart = md[md['A or B'].str.contains('AAAA')].groupby([md['ID']]).agg({'Start Date': 'min'})

    df['earliestStartDate'] = minStart

    groupedBy = df[df['A or B'].str.contains('AAAA')].groupby([df['ID'], df['Site'].fillna('Other'),df['earliestStartDate']]).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
```

which fails and also tried changing the above to:

```
def do_stuff():
    df = get_csv()
    md = get_csv()

    df['earliestStartDate'] = md.loc[ md['ID'] == df['ID'], 'Start Date'].min()

    groupedBy = df[df['A or B'].str.contains('AAAA')].groupby([df['ID'], df['Site'].fillna('Other'),df['earliestStartDate']]).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})
```

Ideally, I will just change something in the groupedBy instead of having to read the csv twice and aggregate the data twice. Is that possible? If not, what can I change to make the script work? I am trying to test random things to get more experience in Pandas and Python.

I am guessing I have to create two `dataframes` here. One to get the `groupedby` data for all the columns needed (and the SUM of the Value). A second one to get the earliest Start Date and latest End Date for each ID. Then I need to find a way to concatenate the two `dataframes`. Is that a good result or do you think that there is an easier way to achieve that?

UPD: My code where I have created two dataframes (not sure whether this is the right solution) is given below:

```
#Read csv file
df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1",mangle_dupe_cols=True, parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date'])
md = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1",mangle_dupe_cols=True, parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date'])


#Calculate the Clean Value
df['Clean Cost'] = (df['Value'] - df['Value2']) #.apply(lambda x: round(x,0))

#Get the min/max Dates
minMaxDates = md[md['Random'].str.contains('Y')].groupby([md['ID']]).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max'})

#Group by and aggregate (return Earliest Start Date, Latest End Date and SUM of the Values)
groupedBy = df[df['Random'].str.contains('Y')].groupby([df['ID'], df['Site'].fillna('Other')]).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum', 'Value2': 'sum', 'Clean Cost': 'sum'})
```

and if I print the two dataframes, I am getting the following:

[image: minMaxDates]

and

[image]

If I print the df.head(), I am getting the following:

```
  ID A or B Start Date   End Date  Value  Site  Value2 Random                                                 alse.
```

> 0  45221   AAAA 2017-12-30 2017-09-30     14  S111       7      Y 1 
>   45221   AAAA 2017-01-15 2017-09-30     15  S222       7      Y 2 
>   85293   BBBB 2017-05-12 2017-07-24     29  S111       3      Y 3 
>   85293   AAAA 2017-03-22 2017-10-14     32  S222       4      Y 4 
>   45221   AAAA 2017-01-15 2017-09-30     30  S222       7      Y

A link of the file is given here:[LINK](https://mega.nz/#!VQp1URjI!9hguMZerhmuSW411enn4ze6oK8pYNXVlALirtr42MHY)

Comment: Can you provide a small sample dataframe, enough to replicate your code?

Comment: @ASGM I have printed the groupedby and minMaxDates. I have updated the question. Is that enough?

Comment: Can you provide it as code instead of images?  You're much more likely to get a useful answer if someone can copy-paste the code you've posted, replicate your problem, and then find a solution.

Comment: @ASGM I have uploaded the file. I have also pasted the df.head() (not an image this time). Let me know if that is OK generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('sampleBionic.csv')
print (df)
      ID A or B  Start Date    End Date  Value  Site  Value2 Random
0  45221   AAAA  12/30/2017  09/30/2017     14  S111       7      Y
1  45221   AAAA  01/15/2017  09/30/2017     15  S222       7      Y
2  85293   BBBB  05/12/2017  07/24/2017     29  S111       3      Y
3  85293   AAAA  03/22/2017  10/14/2017     32  S222       4      Y
4  45221   AAAA  01/15/2017  09/30/2017     30  S222       7      Y

groupedBy = (df[df['A or B'].str.contains('AAAA')]
                            .groupby([df['ID'], df['Site'].fillna('Other'),])
                            .agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'}))
print (groupedBy)    
            Start Date    End Date  Value
ID    Site                               
45221 S111  12/30/2017  09/30/2017     14
      S222  01/15/2017  09/30/2017     45
85293 S222  03/22/2017  10/14/2017     32

g = groupedBy.groupby(level=0)              
groupedBy['Start Date'] = g['Start Date'].transform('min') 
groupedBy['End Date'] = g['End Date'].transform('max')
print (groupedBy)
            Start Date    End Date  Value
ID    Site                               
45221 S111  01/15/2017  09/30/2017     14
      S222  01/15/2017  09/30/2017     45
85293 S222  03/22/2017  10/14/2017     32
```

Comment: It works fine :) Your script has less lines than mine.

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately `transform` does not work with `dictionary` like `agg`, so need 2 rows. Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a script that does what I want. I will paste the answer in case somebody needs it in the future. Jezrael's answer worked fine too. So, considering that the original csv is like this:
[image]

my sript is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import time
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import datetime


def get_csv():
        #Read csv file
        df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1",mangle_dupe_cols=True, parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date'])
        df = df[df['A or B'].str.contains('AAAA')]

        return df

def do_stuff():
    df = get_csv()

    #Get the min Start Date, max End date, sum of the Value and Value2 and calculate the Net Cost
    varA      = 'ID';
    dfGrouped = df.groupby(varA, as_index=False).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max'}).copy();

    varsToKeep = ['ID', 'Site', 'Random', 'Start Date_grp', 'End Date_grp', 'Value', 'Value2', ];
    dfTemp = pd.merge(df, dfGrouped, how='inner', on='ID', suffixes=(' ', '_grp'), copy=True)[varsToKeep];

    dfBreakDown = dfTemp.groupby(['ID', 'Site', 'Random', 'Start Date_grp',
        'End Date_grp']).sum()

    #Calculate the Net Cost
    dfTemp['Net Cost'] = (dfTemp['Value'] - dfTemp['Value2'])

    groupedBy = dfTemp.groupby(['ID', 'Site', 'Random']).agg({'Start Date_grp': 'min', 'End Date_grp': 'max', 'Value': 'sum', 'Value2': 'sum', 'Net Cost': 'sum'})

    csvoutput(groupedBy)

def csvoutput(df):
        #Csv output
        df.to_csv(path_or_buf='OUT.csv', sep=',', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, mode='w', encoding=None, compression=None, quoting=None, quotechar='"', line_terminator='\n', chunksize=None, tupleize_cols=False, date_format=None, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, decimal='.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        #  start things here
        do_stuff()
```